Cannot open most applications when using ubuntu 24.04 remote login from windows rdp. How would I make it work?
I recently installed ubuntu 24.04 on my laptop to try and use it as a server. I used the built-in desktop share to control my laptop from my windows pc using Remote Desktop Connection (the one built-in windows) , but I got annoyed that I needed to keep the laptop open and active to not have the session terminate.
I am now trying to use the ubuntu Remote login instead, which allows me to keep my laptop screen off, however I have run into this issue that I have no idea how to solve: I cannot open many of the applications, the most notable ones being nautilus and settings. I have searched for hours and I can't find anyone else with the same issue as me. here is the crash log file of settings (i don't know what is useful so I put as I much I could but I had to trim the threadTrace, sorry):
ApportVersion: 2.28.1-0ubuntu3.1
CasperMD5CheckResult: pass
Disassembly:
 => 0x7c529e9cf76e <_dl_close+30>:  cmpb   $0x0,0x357(%rbx)
    0x7c529e9cf775 <_dl_close+37>:  jne    0x7c529e9cf7be <_dl_close+110>
    0x7c529e9cf777 <_dl_close+39>:  mov    0x350(%rbx),%edx
    0x7c529e9cf77d <_dl_close+45>:  test   %edx,%edx
    0x7c529e9cf77f <_dl_close+47>:  je     0x7c529e9cf800 <_dl_close+176>
    0x7c529e9cf781 <_dl_close+49>:  movabs $0x3ffffffff,%rax
    0x7c529e9cf78b <_dl_close+59>:  sub    $0x1,%edx
    0x7c529e9cf78e <_dl_close+62>:  movabs $0x200000000,%rcx
    0x7c529e9cf798 <_dl_close+72>:  mov    %edx,0x350(%rbx)
    0x7c529e9cf79e <_dl_close+78>:  and    0x350(%rbx),%rax
    0x7c529e9cf7a5 <_dl_close+85>:  cmp    %rcx,%rax
    0x7c529e9cf7a8 <_dl_close+88>:  jne    0x7c529e9cf7da <_dl_close+138>
    0x7c529e9cf7aa <_dl_close+90>:  mov    0x36970(%rip),%eax        # 0x7c529ea06120 <dl_close_state.2>
    0x7c529e9cf7b0 <_dl_close+96>:  test   %eax,%eax
    0x7c529e9cf7b2 <_dl_close+98>:  jne    0x7c529e9cf7d0 <_dl_close+128>
    0x7c529e9cf7b4 <_dl_close+100>: xor    %esi,%esi
InstallationDate: Installed on 2024-08-17 (1 days ago)
InstallationMedia: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS "Noble Numbat" - Release amd64 (20240424)
JournalErrors:
 Aug 18 21:51:29 LLC gnome-shell[30639]: meta_window_set_stack_position_no_sync: assertion 'window->stack_position >= 0' failed
 Aug 18 21:51:32 LLC gnome-shell[30639]: surface_state_changed: assertion 'wl_window->has_last_sent_configuration' failed
 Aug 18 21:51:33 LLC gnome-shell[30639]: Can't update stage views actor Window drag helper [ClutterActor] is on because it needs an allocation.
NonfreeKernelModules: nvidia_modeset nvidia
ProcCpuinfoMinimal:
 processor  : 7
 vendor_id  : GenuineIntel
 cpu family : 6
 model      : 158
 model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
 stepping   : 9
 microcode  : 0xf8
 cpu MHz        : 3401.303
 cache size : 6144 KB
 physical id    : 0
 siblings   : 8
 core id        : 3
 cpu cores  : 4
 apicid     : 7
 initial apicid : 7
 fpu        : yes
 fpu_exception  : yes
 cpuid level    : 22
 wp     : yes
 bogomips   : 5599.85
 clflush size   : 64
 cache_alignment    : 64
 address sizes  : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
 power management:
ProcVersionSignature: Ubuntu 6.8.0-40.40-generic 6.8.12
Registers:
 rax            0x0                 0
 rbx            0x0                 0
 rcx            0x7c529e9cf750      136694290249552
 rdx            0x1                 1
 rsi            0x0                 0
 rdi            0x7c529ea05a08      136694290471432
 rbp            0x7ffff86362f0      0x7ffff86362f0
 rsp            0x7ffff86362e0      0x7ffff86362e0
 r8             0x0                 0
 r9             0x7                 7
 r10            0x64c2a1aa2300      110787098714880
 r11            0x9f06353ab2a2ce39  -6987839245597356487
 r12            0x7c529ea05a08      136694290471432
 r13            0x7ffff8636498      140737360651416
 r14            0x1                 1
 r15            0x0                 0
 rip            0x7c529e9cf76e      0x7c529e9cf76e <_dl_close+30>
 eflags         0x10246             [ PF ZF IF RF ]
 cs             0x33                51
 ss             0x2b                43
 ds             0x0                 0
 es             0x0                 0
 fs             0x0                 0
 gs             0x0                 0
 fs_base        0x7c5296ed45c0      136694161294784
 gs_base        0x0                 0
SegvAnalysis:
 Segfault happened at: 0x7c529e9cf76e <_dl_close+30>:   cmpb   $0x0,0x357(%rbx)
 PC (0x7c529e9cf76e) ok
 source "$0x0" ok
 destination "0x357(%rbx)" (0x00000357) not located in a known VMA region (needed writable region)!
SegvReason: writing NULL VMA
Stacktrace:
 #0  _dl_close (_map=0x0) at ./elf/dl-close.c:770
         map = 0x0
 #1  0x00007c529e9ce51c in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7ffff8636430, operate=0x7c529e9cf750 <_dl_close>, args=0x0) at ./elf/dl-catch.c:237
         errcode = 32767
         c = {exception = 0x7ffff8636430, errcode = 0x7ffff863632c, env = {{__jmpbuf = {140737360651415, 5313450201297623360, 140737360651424, 140737360651416, 1, 0, 5313450201402480960, 5685767253934643520}, __mask_was_saved = -127703568, __saved_mask = {__val = {136694290471512, 140737360651360, 0, 5313450201400383808, 5685767253934643520, 5, 0, 1, 0, 140737360651472, 136694290285052, 47, 140737360651367, 140737360651328, 136694290245225, 110787098714911}}}}}
         old = 0x0
 #2  0x00007c529e9ce669 in _dl_catch_error (objname=0x7ffff8636498, errstring=0x7ffff86364a0, mallocedp=0x7ffff8636497, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at ./elf/dl-catch.c:256
         exception = {objname = 0x7ffff8636470 "\340dc\370\377\177", errstring = 0x7c529c4add9e <__GI___libc_free+126> "dD\211#H\203\304\030[A\\A]]\303\017\037", message_buffer = 0x7ffff86364b0 ""}
         errorcode = <optimized out>
 #3  0x00007c529c497c73 in _dlerror_run (operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at ./dlfcn/dlerror.c:138
         result = <optimized out>
         objname = 0x0
         errstring = 0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>
         malloced = false
         errcode = <optimized out>
 
StacktraceAddressSignature: /usr/bin/gnome-control-center:11:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+51c:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+669:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+6fc73:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+6f9a6:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-vulkan-producer.so.535.183.01+1e0d:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-vulkan-producer.so.535.183.01+20db:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.535.183.01+1520af2:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.535.183.01+154ae3f:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.535.183.01+156ee5d:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.535.183.01+4bb50:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1.3.275+340da:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/zink_dri.so+a62b0c:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/zink_dri.so+a63dca:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/zink_dri.so+a69766:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/zink_dri.so+a6998d
StacktraceTop:
 _dl_close (_map=0x0) at ./elf/dl-close.c:770
 __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7ffff8636430, operate=0x7c529e9cf750 <_dl_close>, args=0x0) at ./elf/dl-catch.c:237
 _dl_catch_error (objname=0x7ffff8636498, errstring=0x7ffff86364a0, mallocedp=0x7ffff8636497, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at ./elf/dl-catch.c:256
 _dlerror_run (operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at ./dlfcn/dlerror.c:138
 __dlclose (handle=<optimized out>) at ./dlfcn/dlclose.c:31
Tags: noble third-party-packages wayland-session
........
Title: gnome-control-center crashed with SIGSEGV in _dl_close()
UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)
_MarkForUpload: True
separator: 

also, when i try to launch settings by using terminal and typing gnome-control-center , i get Segmentation fault (core dumped). However, when I run the command as root, i get this:
23:07:06.5792     cc-display-panel[53832]: WARNING: Missing property 'ApplyMonitorsConfigAllowed' on DisplayConfig API
23:07:06.5793     cc-display-panel[53832]: WARNING: Missing property 'NightLightSupported' on DisplayConfig API
23:07:06.8850     cc-display-panel[53832]: WARNING: Error calling GetCurrentState: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
23:07:07.0678      cc-ubuntu-panel[53832]: WARNING: Failed to get gnome-shell extensions: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying


I am wondering if anyone has a solution or can direct me to where I could get help.

Try nvidia driver 470
It fails on more recent
